# How to validate an array of type Enum with EnumDataType using Data Annotations with C# from a unit test?

Tags: c#, validation, unit-testing, model-view-controller, data-annotations

In ColorSettings model shown below, I'm able to validate property MyColor with EnumDataType to make sure that only the value defined in ColorsEnum can be entered as shown below. This works fine for a single string value of type ColorsEnum.

```
[Test]
public void ColorSettingsModel_MyColorEnum_Invalid()
{
  var sut = GetColorSettingsModel();
  sut.MyColor = "wrong color value";

  var context = new ValidationContext(sut, null, null);
  var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
  var isModelStateValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(sut, context, validationResults, true);

  Assert.AreEqual(1, validationResults.Count);
  Assert.IsTrue(validationResults.Any(x => x.ErrorMessage == "MyColorEnum"));
}
```

How can I validate the field SelectedColors using a similar method that contains an array of type ColorsEnum? Is there a way to apply EnumDataType attribute to an array of type ColorsEnum?

```
public enum ColorsEnum
{
  red,
  blue,
  green
}

public class ColorSettings
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "MyColorRequired")]
  [EnumDataType(typeof(ColorsEnum), ErrorMessage = "MyColorEnum")]
  public string MyColor { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "SelectedColorsRequired")]
  // How to validate an array of type ColorsEnum with EnumDataType ?
  public string[] SelectedColors { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: If you implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` you can add this in the GetErrors method. Do you implement this interface or do you use another validation pattern?

Comment: I use a standard validation pattern in .Net Mvc to validate a model inside controller and exactly the same is used in unit test. From my understanding there is a build in attribute EnumDataType but it only works when property is of type ColorsEnum. I need a way to validate an array of type ColorsEnum.

Comment: I think you need to write custom validation code for this, either in your model or somewhere else :/. At least I don't know an attribute which does what you want.

Comment: Did you come up with an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom attribute like the one below :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class EnumDataTypeArrayAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{
    public EnumDataTypeArrayAttribute(Type enumType)
        : base("Enumeration")
    {
        if (enumType == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Type cannot be null");
        }
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Type must be an enum");
        }
        this.EnumType = enumType;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;
        var at = value.GetType();
        if (!at.IsArray) return false;
        var t = at.GetElementType();
        if (t != this.EnumType) return false;
        foreach (var v in value as Array)
        {
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(this.EnumType, v))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Type EnumType
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Then annotate your property or whatever you want to validate like that :

```
[EnumDataTypeArray(typeof(SomeEnumType))]
public SomeEnumType[] Types { get; set; }
```